# SurveyMonkey API Rate Limits

Tags: surveymonkey

I have just set up a new OAuth Application for a SurveyMonkey integration we would like to build and noted the following:

```
Key Rate Limits
2   Calls per second
1,000   Calls per day
```

Is this global/application wide or per access token (i.e. per user who authenticates with the application)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key limits are per application, not per user.  If your app requires a higher rate limit, you can request your limit be raised from the link at the bottom of the following page:

https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/limits

Comment: Thanks - seems a little odd if you are creating an app which can be installed/authenticated by anybody then this does not give much confidence that individual users will not receive quota errors.

Will try to apply for higher rate limits.